# Difference between sort and sortInPlace in swift 2?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have been trying to use the sortInPlace function in swift but it is not working. When I use the sort function instead of sortinplace it works.

Please explain the difference between these 2 function. It would be very helpful if you can provide small code sample demonstrating the use of both functions.

Comment: `sort` _returns_ a sorted array containing the elements of `self` leaving `self` intact, while `sortInPlace` just sorts `self`.

Comment: You can easily find out by yourself: CMD-click on the symbol respectively and read the description

Comment: In Swift 3 there is no `sortInPlace`. instead there is a `sort` & `sorted`. See my answer below

Answer (score 14):

```
var mutableArray = [19, 7, 8, 45, 34]

// function sort sorts the array but does not change it. Also it has return

mutableArray.sort()

mutableArray
// prints 19, 7, 8, 45, 34

// function sortInPlace will mutate the array. Do not have return

mutableArray.sortInPlace()

mutableArray
// prints 7, 8, 19, 34, 45
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, in Swift 3 there is no `sortInPlace`. instead there is a `sort` & `sorted`.

```
var mutableArray = [19, 7, 8, 45, 34]

mutableArray.sortInPlace() // error : 'sortInPlace()' has been renamed to 'sort()'

mutableArray.sort() // 
print(mutableArray) // [7, 8, 19, 34, 45]

mutableArray.sorted()

print(mutableArray) // [19, 7, 8, 45, 34]
let anotherArray = mutableArray.sorted()

print(anotherArray) // [7, 8, 19, 34, 45]
```

If you want to use `sortInPlace` or `sort` which are mutating functions then the array must be a `var`, otherwise you could get a **misleading** error saying:

> 'sort()' has been renamed to 'sorted()'

Comment: The question is specifically tagged "swift2", I'm not sure we have to post syntax updates to such a specific question about a specific version...

Comment: @EricAya True. I agree But one might not know that `sortInPlace` is specific to Swift 2. I was looking around to find what is `sortInPlace` and realized there is no such thing in Swift 3.

Comment: Sure. :) Well, it doesn't hurt to have this answer I guess. It's just that I'm fixing off-topic stuff, and I wasn't sure about this one. :p