# Sorting Array in Swift3

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

In my code, I have a struct like the following:

```
struct Object {
    var name: String
    var count: Int
```

I am now creating an array of 10 Objects with random names and random counts.

Is there an easy way to
a) sort them alphabetically
b) sort them numerically in ascending order

Basically, there will be an array like so:
`[Object1, Object2, Object3]`.
Every Object has a `name` and `count` attribute, and I want the objects in that list be sorted via these two attributes.

Solution in Swift2 (using this solution: [StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603960/swift-sort-array-of-objects-with-multiple-criteria):

```
Object.sort{
        if $0.name != $1.name {
            return $0.name < $1.name
        }
        else {
            //suits are the same
            return $0.count < $1.count
        }
    }
```

However, this has been renamed to `sorted(by: )` in Swift3, and I don't quit get how to do that.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2296801-sort

Comment: While this link has provided me with some explanation, I still have no clue how to do this with elements. Also, in none of the example things are sorted by 2 criteria, e.g. first name & last name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Sort array of objects with multiple criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603960/swift-sort-array-of-objects-with-multiple-criteria)

Comment: In order to preserve the Stack Overflow Q&A format, in the future I'd suggest you do not edit your question to repeat the answer shown below (or found elsewhere). And if you really felt compelled to provide your own answer, then [post it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), below, rather than editing your question to include it there.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want to sort alphabetically and then numerically, you can:

```
var array = ["A2", "B7", "A4", "C3", "A1", "A10"]
array.sort { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }
```

That produces:

> ["A1", "A2", "A4", "A10", "B7", "C3"]

I added `A10` to your array, because without it, a simple alphabetic sort would have been sufficient. But I'm assuming you wanted `A10` after `A4`, in which case the numeric comparison will do the job for you.

---

You changed the example to be a struct with two properties. In that case, you can do something like:

```
struct Foo {
    var name: String
    var count: Int
}

var array = [
    Foo(name:"A", count: 2),
    Foo(name:"B", count: 7),
    Foo(name:"A", count: 7),
    Foo(name:"C", count: 3),
    Foo(name:"A", count: 1),
    Foo(name:"A", count: 10)
]

array.sort { (object1, object2) -> Bool in
    if object1.name == object2.name {
        return object1.count < object2.count
    } else {
        return object1.name < object2.name
    }
}
```

Or, more concisely:

```
array.sort { $0.name == $1.name ? $0.count < $1.count : $0.name < $1.name }
```

Or

```
array.sort { ($0.name, $0.count) < ($1.name, $1.count) }
```

Note, rather than putting this logic in the closure, I'd actually make `Foo` conform to `Comparable`:

```
struct Foo {
    var name: String
    var count: Int
}

extension Foo: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.name, lhs.count) == (rhs.name, rhs.count)
    }
}

extension Foo: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.name, lhs.count) < (rhs.name, rhs.count)
    }
}
```

This keeps the comparison logic nicely encapsulated within the `Foo` type, where it belongs.

Then you can just do the following to sort in place:

```
var array = ...
array.sort()
```

Or, alternatively, you can return a new array if you don't want to sort the original one in place:

```
let array = ...
let sortedArray = array.sorted()
```

Comment: No, in Swift 3, `sorted` is the version that returns a new array. `sort` is the version that sorts in place.

Comment: Then you must not be sorting in place, but rather trying to return it as a new array, in which case you'd do `let sortedArray = array.sorted() { ... }`.

Comment: Sorry that I can't do anything more than up vote your answer and comments, you deserve way more!

Comment: why did you write **static** func?

Comment: In Swift 2, the equality and comparison operators were implemented as globals, but in Swift 3 they are defined as `static` methods of the type, which keeps your code a little better organized. See [Improving operators in protocols](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9cf2685293108ea3efcbebb7ee6a8618b83d4a90/proposals/0091-improving-operators-in-protocols.md).

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, you can still do it the Swift2 way in Swift 3, ie define it as a global func ? However it's not recommended?

Comment: It's a poor design, IMHO, but, yes, you can do it the old way, too.

Answer (score 11):

Narusan, maybe this will help you.
Let's say you have an array with your struct objects called objArray, then you can order it by the code bellow:

```
var objArray = [Object]()
objArray.append(Object(name:"Steve", count:0))
objArray.append(Object(name:"Alex", count:1))

objNameSorted = objArray.sorted (by: {$0.name < $1.name})
objNCountSorted = objArray.sorted (by: {$0.count < $1.count})
```

Comment: You can still use shorthand for `sorted`:

    objNameSorted = objArray.sorted { $0 < $1 }

While less readable, it more closely mimics the `sort` syntax.

Answer (score 7):

You can still use shorthand for `sorted`:

```
objNameSorted = objArray.sorted { $0 < $1 }
```

While less readable, it more closely mimics the `sort` syntax.