# Move some objects of array at the end in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a list of conversation which needs to be sorted on last updated time. I am able to do this but now i also need to add a check that if user is not included in conversation then it should appear at the end of list.

```
func sortConversationList () {
self.conversationList = self.conversationList.sorted(by: { $0.lastupdatedTime! > $1.lastupdatedTime! })
    for (index, conversation) in self.conversationList.enumerated() {
        if (conversation.isIncluded == kNo) {
            self.conversationList.move(at: index, to: self.conversationList.endIndex-1)
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
 mutating func move(at oldIndex: Int, to newIndex: Int) {
        self.insert(self.remove(at: oldIndex), at: newIndex)
    }
```

but this is not working properly. Any better way to do this in swift ?

Comment: Mutating the list your sorting, in the middle of sorting... yikes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is far too complicated. You have two sorting criteria:

1. `isIncluded` – `true` values should be sorted before `false` values,
2. `lastupdatedTime` – larger values should be sorted first.

That can be done with a single `sort()` call:

```
conversationList.sort(by: { 
    if $0.isIncluded != $1.isIncluded {
        return $0.isIncluded
    } else {
        return $0.lastupdatedTime > $1.lastupdatedTime
    }
})
```

This assumes `isIncluded` is a boolean variable (which would be sensible). If it is an integer (as you indicated in the comments)
then it is even simpler: (compare [Swift - Sort array of objects with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603960/swift-sort-array-of-objects-with-multiple-criteria/37612765#37612765)):

```
conversationList.sort(by: {
    ($0.isIncluded, $0.lastupdatedTime) > ($1.isIncluded, $1.lastupdatedTime)
})
```

Comment: Sorting is working fine but sometimes isIncluded true values comes at the top and sometime false value. I updated the first if condition to "if $0.isIncluded != $1.isIncluded && $0.isIncluded ! ==  false" and it didn't worked. :-|

Comment: Consider isIncluded values 1,0 instead of true false. 1 values should be at top and 0 values should be at bottom.

Comment: @aqsaarshad: What type has `isIncluded`? What is `isIncluded1` ?

Comment: 'isIncluded' is of type int. And i have edited my comment.

Comment: Then `return $0.isIncluded > $1.included` in the first case.

Comment: My bad, problem was in my data. For hardcode data its working fine. Thanks.