# Sort a heterogeneous collection by type and attribute in Swift

Tags: swift, collections

I've got a heterogeneous collection of different types that all conform to the same protocol. I want to sort the array by type and then the name attribute. For example I want this array of animals to be sorted by type in this order: Dog, Bird and then Fish, and if they are of the same type I want to sort by name. Here's the code:

```
import Foundation

protocol Animal {
    var name: String { get set }
}

class Dog: Animal {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Bird: Animal {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Fish: Animal {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let dogA = Dog(name: "A")
let dogB = Dog(name: "B")
let birdA = Bird(name: "A")
let birdB = Bird(name: "B")
let fishA = Fish(name: "A")
let fishB = Fish(name: "B")

let animals: [Animal] = [fishB, fishA, birdB, birdA, dogB, dogA]

let sortedAnimals = animals.sorted { first, second -> Bool in
    if first is Dog && !(second is Dog) {
        return true
    } else if first is Dog && second is Dog {
        return first.name < second.name
    }

    if first is Bird && !(second is Bird) {
        return true
    } else if first is Bird && second is Bird {
        return first.name < second.name
    }

    if first is Fish && !(second is Fish) {
        return true
    } else if first is Fish && second is Fish {
        return first.name < second.name
    }

    return first.name < second.name
}

sortedAnimals
```

This works, and results in the correct sort order:

```
{name "A", type "Dog"}
{name "B", type "Dog"}
{name "A", type "Bird"}
{name "B", type "Bird"}
{name "A", type "Fish"}
{name "B", type "Fish"}
```

But since in the production code I have over 30 different types in the collection this kind of repetition feels very duplicative. How can I do this kind of a sort without so much repetitive code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `[Animal.Type]` to establish the ordering, and then compare the types for equality first to decide if you need to sort by `name` or by `type`.

```
let order: [Animal.Type] = [Dog.self, Bird.self, Fish.self]

let sortedAnimals = animals.sorted { first, second -> Bool in
    let firstIndex = order.firstIndex { $0 == type(of: first) } ?? Int.max
    let secondIndex = order.firstIndex { $0 == type(of: second) } ?? Int.max

    if firstIndex == secondIndex {
        return first.name < second.name
    } else {
        return firstIndex < secondIndex
    }
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. As written, missing types will be sorted to the end of the array by `name`.
2. You might want to add:

   ```
   assert(firstIndex != Int.max, "missing type \(type(of: first)) from order array")
   assert(secondIndex != Int.max, "missing type \(type(of: second)) from order array")
   ```

   to catch types missing from the `order` array.  While you could just force unwrap the result of `firstIndex(where:)`, the `assert` provides the ability to find missing types in *Debug* builds, but goes away in *Release* builds.
3. Tuple comparison (as explained by @Hamish with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612765/1630618)) can be used to replace the `if` statement above with:

   ```
   return (firstIndex, first.name) < (secondIndex, second.name)
   ```

   Thanks for the reminder, @MartinR!

Comment: Possibly just a detail of the sample, but the sorting demonstrated in the question is not alphabetical by type: Dog comes before Bird.

Comment: Doh! They type stored as a string was just an artifact of how I was testing the code in the playground. The actual objects don't have that. Let me remove that from the code.

Comment: And yes, Josh, the idea was to sort by type arbitrarily, not alphabetically.

Comment: I updated the answer to eliminate the type stored as a `String`.

Comment: If you want to catch missing types in the order array then you could also force-unwrap the result from `firstIndex(where:)` :)

Comment: @MartinR, good point.  Also, using `guard let firstOrder = ...` else { `fatalError("missing type")}` would be another way to go.

Comment: Great answer. Very elegant. Thank you!

Comment: Sorting with multiple criteria (here: index, name) can be done elegantly with tuple comparison, as @Hamish demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612765/1187415.

Comment: So, my last 5 lines of code would become `return (firstIndex, first.name) < (secondIndex, second.name)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort a heterogeneous group of `Animal` objects by a property `type` then that property should be in the protocol. Once you make that change this becomes trivial.

Comment: Just updated the code. The type: String attribute was just an artifact of how I was testing swift playground code. It's removed now.