# Array how to sort by mutiple property by Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I want to sort array data by number value like "90 > 80 > 70 ...> 10".
But I don't know how to compare mutiple property.

```
struct Item {
   let number1: Double
   let number2: Double
   let number3: Double
}

let item1 = Item(number1:0, number2:0, number3:10)
let item2 = Item(number1:20, number2:0, number3:0)
let item3 = Item(number1:0, number2:30, number3:0)
let item4 = Item(number1:0, number2:0, number3:40)
let item5 = Item(number1:0, number2:50, number3:0)
let item6 = Item(number1:60, number2:0, number3:0)
let item7 = Item(number1:0, number2:70, number3:0)
let item8 = Item(number1:0, number2:0, number3:80)
let item9 = Item(number1:0, number2:90, number3:0)

var array:[Item] = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9]

array = array.sorted { (item, nextItem) -> Bool in {
     item.number3 < nextItem.number3 //how to add item's number2 & number1 into here.
}
```

Comment: What should your final result look like?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: [Sort array of objects with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603960/swift-sort-array-of-objects-with-multiple-criteria).

Comment: Just compare number which is bigger and smaller. 
big array like [item9,item8,item7....,item1]

Comment: Compare which numbers? number1, number2, or number3?

Comment: @MartinR mix them

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr Do you want to compare by sum of 3 numbers?

Comment: At present it is unclear what you are asking for. – Is `Item(number1:20, number2:0, number3:0)` larger or smaller than `Item(number1:0, number2:30, number3:0)`? And **why?**

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I think this idea is good

Comment: @MartinR it just my simple project data look like. And I just sort these data

Comment: There is no “just sort” without specifying a sorting order – and that is *your task.* We cannot guess what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the elements by the sum of 3 numbers

```
array = array.sorted { (item, nextItem) -> Bool in
    let itemSum = item.number1 + item.number2 + item.number3
    let nextItemSum = nextItem.number1 + nextItem.number2 + nextItem.number3
    return itemSum > nextItemSum
}
```

> [Item(number1: 0.0, number2: 90.0, number3: 0.0),
>   Item(number1: 0.0, number2: 0.0, number3: 80.0),
>   Item(number1: 0.0, number2: 70.0, number3: 0.0),
>   Item(number1: 60.0, number2: 0.0, number3: 0.0),
>   Item(number1: 0.0, number2: 50.0, number3: 0.0),
>   Item(number1: 0.0, number2: 0.0, number3: 40.0),
>   Item(number1: 0.0, number2: 30.0, number3: 0.0),
>   Item(number1: 20.0, number2: 0.0, number3: 0.0),
>   Item(number1: 0.0, number2: 0.0, number3: 10.0)]

Comment: I got this Error. The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Comment: should `Item(number1: 20.0, number2: 20.0, number3: 20.0)` really be bigger than `Item(number1: 50.0, number2: 0.0, number3: 0.0)`?