# Sorting on more than two elements in an array of structs

Tags: swift

I have multiple (multi-unit) properties that are located at the same sites and I want to sort them by site address, then property name at that address (tower name), and then by the number of bedrooms for the tower.

For example:

```
struct Property: Hashable {
    var propertyName: String = ""
    var unitNumber: Int = 0
    var bedrooms: Double = 0
    var siteAddress: String = ""
} // Property

var properties: Array<Property> = []
properties.append(Property(propertyName: "Tower A", unitNumber: 211, bedrooms: 2.5, siteAddress: "123 Main Street")
properties.append(Property(propertyName: "Tower A", unitNumber: 508, bedrooms: 1, siteAddress: "413 Another Street")
properties.append(Property(propertyName: "Tower B", unitNumber: 816, bedrooms: 2.5, siteAddress: "123 Main Street")
properties.append(Property(propertyName: "Tower A", unitNumber: 923, bedrooms: 1, siteAddress: "123 Main Street")
properties.append(Property(propertyName: "Tower A", unitNumber: 104, bedrooms: 3, siteAddress: "123 Main Street")
properties.append(Property(propertyName: "Tower B", unitNumber: 304, bedrooms: 2, siteAddress: "123 Main Street")
properties.append(Property(propertyName: "Tower B", unitNumber: 222, bedrooms: 1, siteAddress: "413 Another Street")
properties.append(Property(propertyName: "Tower A", unitNumber: 601, bedrooms: 2, siteAddress: "413 Another Street")

// Sort the available units
properties = properties.sorted(by: { this, next in
    if this.siteAddress == next.siteAddress && this.propertyName == next.propertyName && this.bedrooms < next.bedrooms {
        return true
    } else if this.siteAddress == next.siteAddress && this.propertyName == next.propertyName && this.bedrooms > next.bedrooms {
        return false
    } else if this.siteAddress == next.siteAddress && this.propertyName < next.propertyName {
        return true
    } else if this.siteAddress == next.siteAddress && this.propertyName > next.propertyName {
        return false
    } else if this.siteAddress < next.siteAddress {
        return true
    } else if this.siteAddress > next.siteAddress {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
})
```

Desired results:

- 123 Main Street

  - Tower A

    - 923, 1br
    - 211, 2.5br
    - 104, 3br
  - Tower B

    - 304, 2br
    - 816, 2.5br
- 413 Another Street

  - Tower A

    - 508, 1br
    - 601, 2br
  - Tower B

    - 222, 1br

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603960

Comment: Yes and no.  I couldn't find a post that more than two elements were being used.  The answer below answers my question.

Comment: Both [Hamish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612765/3141234) (of using tuples and the several `<` operators already implemented for them) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37604010/3141234) (using `if let` statements) scale to more than 2 properties. See the "repeat for all other fields in the sorting" comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need that many if statements in your closure. A simpler way of writing it would be:

```swift
properties.sort { this, next in
    if this.siteAddress != next.siteAddress {
        return this.siteAddress < next.siteAddress
    } else if this.propertyName != next.propertyName {
        return this.propertyName < next.propertyName
    } else {
        return this.bedrooms < next.bedrooms
    }
}
```

But there's an even simpler way. Because the Swift standard library overloads the `<` operator to support tuples of different lengths, you can simply use:

```swift
properties.sort {
    ($0.siteAddress, $0.propertyName, $0.bedrooms) < ($1.siteAddress, $1.propertyName, $1.bedrooms)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I for the life of me couldn't figure that out.  So simple!