# Array sorting by property

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a set of object array like this:

```
[ProductDetails(name: "Tai Tou Choy",
    productDescription: "",
    deliveryTime: "24 hours",
    img1: "https://api.com.my/images/data/4983-img1-1463122485.jpg",
    thumbImg1: "https://api.com.my/images/data/thumbs/4983-img1-1463122485.jpg",
    img2: "",
    thumbImg2: "",
    img3: "",
    thumbImg3: "",
    videoLink: "",
    sku: "0000000004983",
    relatedProduct: "",
    priceOption: [PriceOption(id: 9931,
                            label: "500g",
                            price: "4.56",
                            promo: "0",
                            quantity: 999)],
    deliveryZone: [DeliveryZone(zone: "3")],
    deliveryZoneName: [DeliveryZoneName(zoneName: "Within Klang Valley")],
    qrCode: "4983"),
ProductDetails(name: "Penguin Asam Jawa",
    productDescription: "",
    deliveryTime: "24 hours",
    img1: "https://api.com.my/images/data/1004-img1.jpg",
    thumbImg1: "https://api.com.my/images/data/thumbs/1004-img1.jpg",
    img2: "",
    thumbImg2: "",
    img3: "",
    thumbImg3: "",
    videoLink: "",
    sku: "0000000001004",
    relatedProduct: "",
    priceOption: [PriceOption(id: 6971,
                            label: "1 kg",
                            price: "4.80",
                            promo: "0",
                            quantity: 864)],
    deliveryZone: [DeliveryZone(zone: "3")],
    deliveryZoneName: [DeliveryZoneName(zoneName: "Within Klang Valley")],
    qrCode: "1004")]
```

I wanted to do price sorting from above the arrays, which the PriceOption array is store inside the main array as an object array too. How do i do sorting from PriceOption? I try to do it in this way :

```
    for i in self.productList{

        i.priceOption.sortInPlace{

            $0.price.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.price) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
        }
    }
```

Which return an error "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value :'i' is a 'let' constant."

How to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580177/difference-between-sort-and-sortinplace-in-swift-2 You are trying to sort in place which would update i - however i is immutable. You should use sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This how I solve issue that you present. I am using `sorted` method of the array class.

Solution:

```
self.productList.sorted{ Float($0.priceOption.first!.price)! > Float($1.priceOption.first!.price)!  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for i in self.productList {
    i.priceOption.sort { $0.price < $1.price } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for swift 3 is as following

Ascending:

```
self.productList = self.productList.sorted(by: 
                 {(first: ProductDetails, second: ProductDetails) -> Bool in
                   first.price > second.price
                 }
              )
```

Descending:

```
self.productList = self.productList.sorted(by: 
                 {(first: ProductDetails, second: ProductDetails) -> Bool in
                   first.price > second.price
                 }
              )
```